# Envio de email HTML em projeto Java

Tags: java, html, email

Estou tendo que desenvolver um sistema que faz uma consulta em um banco de dados e os resultados são enviados por email, pra formatação usamos HTML, a primeira forma que vi foi armazenar o código HTML em uma variável, porém a organização fica ruim e não consigo formatar o email com CSS por exemplo, sabem uma forma mais simples de fazer, isolando em um documento único ou algo do tipo?

```
String msg =                    
    "<tr>" +
        "<td><strong>" + chamado.get(i).getChamado()  + "</strong></td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getEstado()   + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getAbertoEm() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getAnalista() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getAreaUsuario()  + " </td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getSumario()  + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getDataPlanejada()  + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + chamado.get(i).getDetalhamento()+ "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a criar toda a estrutura da pagina html e utilizar a tag style para formatar via css.